# How do I find the $n^{th}$ derivative of the given function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function given is $f(x)=\frac{X}{X^4+a^4+a^2 X^2}$.
What I did is that I have expressed the denominator as a square - another square twice and then I finally applied the partial fraction method .
But I am struck after that..
What to do next or is there any other way in which it can be solved?
Please help
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** By replacing $x$ with $ax$, the problem boils down to finding the derivatives of:
$$\begin{align*} g(x)=\frac{x}{x^4+x^2+1} &= \frac{x-x^3}{1-x^6}\overset{(*)}{=}x-x^3+x^7-x^9+x^{13}-x^{15}+\ldots\\&=\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{1}{x-\omega^{-1}}-\frac{1}{x-\omega}+\frac{1}{x-\omega^2}-\frac{1}{x-\omega^{-2}}\right)\end{align*} $$
where $\omega=e^{\pi i/3} = \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}.$

$(*)$: this equality holds only for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Provided $|x|<1$...

Comment: @bartgol: sure, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $g(x)$ at $x=0$ cannot exceed $1$ for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point. The question is, since $f(x)$ is still defined for $|x|>1$, does your final expression still hold?

Comment: @bartgol: the Taylor series is convergent only in a neighbourhood of the origin, but the residue theorem gives the partial fraction decomposition of $g(x)$, hence the last identity always holds, provided that $x$ is not a singularity. Non-believers may just carry on the computations.

Comment: So, I understand the last part (it basically is partial fractions, with complex roots). But I do not understand how the last line "follows" from the infinite series. I think it would be much clearer for the user without the series/residue arguments, simply put as a partial fraction with complex roots. But perhaps that's just me...

Comment: @bartgol: the partial fraction decomposition does not directly follow from the series representation, but both are simple consequences of $g(x)=\frac{x-x^3}{1-x^6}$. That gives the location of the poles *and* the Taylor series in the origin.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to rewrite your function as a composition of functions:

$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{x^4 + a^2x^2 + a^4} = \frac{1}{\frac{x^4 + a^2x^2 + a^4}{x}} = \frac{1}{x^3 + a^2x + \frac{a^4}{x}} = \frac{1}{g(x)}
$$

Then use the chain rule.

Comment: How? I.e., according to your approach, $f^{(n)}(x)$ is... ?

Comment: Well, your question now reduces to find an expression for the $nth$ derivative of the inverse function. You can find that formula here:
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324425?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Computationally unfeasible and clearly the wrong approach, since you do not exploit almost anything about $f(x)$. You are just saying that the derivatives of any differentiable function $f(x)$ are the derivatives of $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}$.

Comment: Given the tags to the question, I "assumed" the user was only interested in computing "a few" derivatives of the function. For small $n$, I think this expression is easier, since the deriatives of $g(x)$ are much easier than those of the original function. Then one only has to glue the pieces together..

Comment: I am not interested in finding some derivative S rather I would like to find the nth one....